# port forwarding in windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, portforwarding

I have two network board in my pc:

The main one has the local ip -> 192.168.1.111
The secondary ones has the local ip -> 192.168.0.200

The main one has internet connection and the second one is connected to a device with the IP 192.168.0.33, it has a http server in port 80.

I have an apache-server in the main connection (port 4422), and I can access from anywhere, what I want now is when I detect a connection from 4422 i want to redirect this connection to 192.168.2.33:80

How can I do this with windows?

Comment: More information can be found here. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731068(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 616, accepted):

I've solved it, it can be done executing:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4422 listenaddress=192.168.1.111 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.0.33
```

To remove forwarding:

```
netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=4422 listenaddress=192.168.1.111
```

[Official docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc731068.aspx)

Comment: Just be sure to have IPv6 installed. Accordingly to this [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555744), netsh need some IPv6 libraries to configure the port proxy feature.

Comment: Yes, netsh portproxy need ipv6 libraries even only use v4tov4

Comment: Also, you can do cleanup using
    `netsh interface portproxy reset`
or 
    `netsh interface portproxy delete`

Comment: Thanks! Does this persist after session logout or rebooting, or do I need to automate this?

Comment: I tried using this technique, and while it worked, it was extremely slow.  Instead.  I found a utility called PassPort (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport) that does the same type of port forwarding bound to a specific NIC, but does not have the performance issues of `netsh`.  It installs and runs well on Win2008SvrR2.

Comment: The command above didn't work for me on Windows7 nor on Windows Server 2003. I had to specify **protocol=tcp** parameter too. Full command: `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4422 listenaddress=192.168.1.111 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.0.33 protocol=tcp`

Comment: NOTE that this *only works on TCP*, so no luck if you wanted to forward UDP traffic.

Comment: Don't forget to allow the connection in firewall:
`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="any_name" protocol=TCP dir=in localip=listen_address localport=listen_port action=allow`

Comment: I tried forwarding to `connectaddress=127.0.0.1` which didn't seem to be possible to get to work at all. Forwarding to the Ethernet's IP solved it for me! Found some hints about that [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e794910b-9325-4ef9-be82-3e57925e6586/problem-with-adding-a-portproxy-using-netsh?forum=winservergen).
Also make sure you have the `Forwarding` flag enabled on the listening interface. See [this article](https://kb.iweb.com/hc/en-us/articles/230239648-Activate-IP-Forwarding-on-the-physical-server-for-a-specific-network-interface) for more info.

Comment: This is actually a proxy, not port forwarding - i.e. the originator is completely hidden from the receiver.

Comment: the term of port-forwarding seems to be used very lightly here.

Answer (score 17):

[nginx](http://nginx.org/) is useful for forwarding HTTP on many platforms including Windows. It's easy to setup and extend with more advanced configuration. A basic configuration could look something like this:

```
events {}

http {
     server {

        listen 192.168.1.111:4422;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.2.33:80/;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution for HTTP forwarding, but only for HTTP forwarding (with all its caveats, e.g. websockets need additional config). For HTTPS forwarding or other arbitrary protocols (e.g. RDP) it's mostly useless.

Comment: That said, it's an incredibly good solution for HTTP forwarding, so I'm glad it's here.

Comment: Why is that? You can stream forward whatever you like, including https

Comment: @uli which settings do you tolking about ... It will be usefull to share

Comment: @UliKöhler Nginx is a tool to decouple TCP connections. You can use it for HTTP, HTTPS, AMQP, WebSockets, whatever. It's used internally by tools all over for redirecting and managing general TCP connectivity. So, this is the correct solution. See also https://netfxharmonics.com/2016/03/nginx

Answer (score 8):

I've used this little utility whenever the need arises:
http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/network/pmapper/freeware.htm

The last time this utility was updated was in 2009. I noticed on my Win10 machine, it hangs for a few seconds when opening new windows sometimes. Other then that UI glitch, it still does its job fine.