# How to redirect localhost to 127.0.0.1:8080?

Tags: windows, apache, localhost

When I check using Apache > Service > Test Port 80, then it shows

```
Your port 80 is actually used by :
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

How can I disable this. Tried every possible way, even via registry, and stopping World Wide Web Publishing.

Comment: Do you happen to be running skype? I experienced that it binds to port 80 and/or port 443 sometimes.

Comment: you must have an application which listens incomming connections which is ready to forward `:80`'s data to `:8080` ..

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions.  Patience is important.  Not everyone on SO knows everything all the time.  You might have to wait for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible.  When you type "localhost" into the browser, it resolves that to "127.0.0.1", and fills in the default port of 80.  If nothing is listening there, it won't connect.  It can't resolve "localhost" to "127.0.0.1:8080".  If you can't use port 80, you have to specify the port you want.  Use a bookmark if it makes it easier for you.

Comment: If major browsers were to support SRV records, everything would be cool. They don't, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically redirecting 127.0.0.1:80 to 127.0.0.1:8080

Win7 has no iptables equivalent. Writing a server that does what you want (listens on a port, copies everything to/from another) should be easy enough. You can find one at this URL: http://www.quantumg.net/portforward.php

`$> netsh
$> interface portproxy
$> add v4tov4 listenport=xxx connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=yyy protocol=tcp`

[or]

[port forwarding in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525703/port-forwarding-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: If your Apache is under your WIn10
Under Win Settings:
- Proxy - Manual proxy setup - Use a proxy server - Turn On
- Type under Manual proxy server http=127.0.0.1:8080;https=127.0.0.1:8080
- Press the Save button
and tell me if it is working.