# Redirect localhost to some other port like 127.0.0.1:8080?

Tags: apache, localhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to redirect localhost to 127.0.0.1:8080?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600408/how-to-redirect-localhost-to-127-0-0-18080)

Due to unidentified problem, any service pid4 is using port 80 of my Windows 7-64 bit PC's. I ultimately decided to change my default port to 8080. But how can I change the way that when I enter localhost in URL, then automatically the data from 127.0.0.1:8080 comes.

I also edited the hosts file as

```
127.0.0.1:8080 localhost
```

but it didn't work. It;s showing as Not Found. Please help me someone.

Comment: @JonLin it's an exact duplicate, word for word.  Same author.  I didn't notice

Answer (score 1):

Some reason you can't disable the service using the port?

Also, the entire 127.*.*.* block is reserved for loopback, you can try to bind the apache server to something like 127.1.1.1 instead of 127.0.0.1

Edit: Is there also some reason you can't just bookmark it, port and all?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you cannot.  The hosts file contains address-name(s) pairs, no ports.

For example, if you put

```
127.0.0.1 localhost mypc someothername
```

in your hosts file, you could use `http://localhost` or `http://mypc` or `http://someothername` and always end up on your local host.

For the process blocking port 80, check [this blog](https://iamfarshad.wordpress.com/2011/09/11/fix-microsoft-httpapi2-0/), possible culprits include SSRS, IIS or Web Deployment Agent Service