# Change Localhost to ip with port

Tags: windows, portforwarding

I am trying to setup a development server in house.  Our IP points to our live server but we have seperate servers set on different ports.

For example our testing server could be on:

```
external: 97.95.xxx.xxx:1234
internal: 192.168.0.100:1234
```

We can view the test server by entering either ip in our browsers.  We want to change all our development computers to access that server by entering "testserver".  We have logged in and edited

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

We have added the following line of code to the systems with no success.

```
97.95.xxx.xxx:1234          testserver
```

If we remove the port number it will connect to our live system.  Is there another system we need to edit to use that port?

Answer (score 0):

when you add the port, your hosts edit is simply wrong.

according to example your hosts entry must look like

```
97.95.xxx.xxx          testserver
```

and accessing the testsystem would be f.e.

```
http://testserver:1234
```

or

```
telnet testserver 1234
```

whatever connectiontype / purpose your connection is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot set ports in the hosts-file,

but there seems to be a way to forward the port:
[port-forwarding-in-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525703/port-forwarding-in-windows)

src: no ports with hosts [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/115282/can-i-configure-the-windows-hosts-file-to-use-ip-address-plus-port)