# PowerShell Copy-Item to remote - custom port

Tags: powershell, port, powershell-remoting, unc

I want to copy some file from local computer to remote in a standard way:

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\some_path\test.txt -Destination \\server\c$\some_other_path\test.txt
```

Unfortunately i have to specify custom port due to routing on `server`. I am pretty new to remote management and powershell. Is there any way to specify port for Copy-Item or UNC path? If not, are they some other reasonable solutions to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use [netsh port forwdaring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525703/port-forwarding-in-windows).

Comment: netsh seems helpful in my case, thank you. With some small additional comment I would accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this is an old thread, I still provide my method here hoping that could help someone else.

According to the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7#syntax), there is no way to specify a port using `Copy-Item`, but you can try to use parameter `ToSession` to achieve your goal if your PS version is higher than **5**, see the new features [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/whats-new/what-s-new-in-windows-powershell-50?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=powershell-7#new-features-in-windows-powershell-50).

Create a session with a specified port:

```bsh
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer -Port $port
```

Then copy files using the session:

```bsh
Copy-Item "C:\some_path\test.txt" -Destination "C:\some_other_path\test.txt" -ToSession $session
```

And don’t forget to remove the session when
you’re done.

```bsh
$session | Remove-PSSession
```

Reference:
[Use PowerShell Copy-Item to File Transfer Over WinRM](https://blog.ipswitch.com/use-powershell-copy-item-cmdlet-transfer-files-winrm)