# Connecting to remote machine from OS X through Windows running VPN client

Tags: windows, macos, proxy, vpn

I have two laptops:

- OSX (capitan)
- windows (8.1)

Both are in network X

I have VPN client running on Windows, connecting to network Y.
(I don't have the mac version of the VPN client).

I need to connect directly from my OSX, to a computer in network Y, through windows.

So we can say windows must act as a proxy.

What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Raka

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525703/port-forwarding-in-windows

Comment: What about this? : https://www.expressvpn.com/support/vpn-setup/share-vpn-connection-windows-manual/

Comment: I just tried it, but I think there's a missing step on that page... how do I tell my mac to use my windows as router?

Comment: O my bad. So this link in expressvpn.com does help. I just had to switch on my mac to the (virtual) LAN I created on windows (by following those steps).

Solved.