# http.ListenAndServe only works for localhost?

Tags: http, go, server

I've been successfully making use of

```
http.ListenAndServe(":80", mux)
```

to host my web service in Go. It only appears to work with localhost however.

```
http.ListenAndServe("192.168.1.83:80", mux)
```

This works for specific connections on this address but is there a way to make it work for any ip address on the server?

**Edit:**

I've checked it with a different port (8080 in this case) and then using ":8080" works as documented.  There appears to be something special about port 80 even when testing on the same machine that means it only actually listens on localhost.

For the avoidance of doubt I'm using Windows and all testing is done on the same physical machine.  I've also checked running with admin privileges and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 21):

`http.ListenAndServe(":80", mux)` is the correct address. [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) uses the [`net`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/) package. Quoting from [`net.Listen()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listen):

> If host is omitted, as in ":8080", **Listen listens on all available interfaces** instead of just the interface with the given host address. See Dial for more details about address syntax.

Know that port 80 is restricted or might be blocked by firewalls on many systems. On unix systems ports under 1024 usually require special permissions. Test the 8080 port for example, because that is not special in this way.

Comment: I'm testing locally still so I wasn't expecting any firewall issues.  Interestingly it does actually work when I move off port 80 to something in the higher range.

Comment: @Saurbaum If you just use `":80"`, that attempts to listen on all available interfaces, so that is not limited to localhost.

Comment: for whatever reason port 80 just isn't working in the manner the documentation describes.  Even on the same computer.

Comment: @Saurbaum Have you tried another, "high" port? For example 8080?

Comment: see my first comment.  Otherwise we will be going in circles.  Yes it works with a port like 8080.  The question now is why does it not work locally with port 80?

Comment: @Saurbaum As said, because port 80 is special. You don't need to change anything in the code, but in your OS or firewall configuration. This is OS specific, but you haven't said anything about your OS and environment.

Comment: Apologies.  I'm using windows for this.  I have elevated the permissions of the application to test as well and then using port 80 only works with localhost even when defined as ":80" for ListenAndServe

Comment: @Saurbaum I've tested it with `":80"`, and I was able to view the started webserver both as `http://localhost` and as `http://<mylocalip>`. Know that to access it via your _external ip_, that most certainly needs opening or forwarding a port on your router!

Comment: I'll raise it as a windows specific bug then on the github page.  I'm well aware that when it goes external it will need the ports forwarding.

Answer (score -2):

No, http.ListenAndServe works for any host or port, however ports below 1024 require root privileges.
You can redirect connections on port 80 as a normal user by using:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo netfilter-persistent save
sudo netfilter-persistent reload
```

Comment: That would only be relevant for external connections surely?  In this case I am testing on the same local box with admin permissions.  Also I'm using Windows not Linux.

Comment: [Port forwarding in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11525703/2604529). As mebtioned by @icza, it has nothing to do with your application and  http.ListenAndServe in particular.

Comment: That would be if there are multiple ip addresses in the machine.  I'm not trying to forward any ports I'm not behind a firewall or a router for these tests.