# Accessing IISExpress for an asp.net core API via IP

Tags: networking, asp.net-core, iis-express

I have an asp.net core project running on IIS Express. The URLs (http://localhost:53142/ and https://localhost:44374/) work if I type into my browser as localhost, however, if i put in my IPv4 ip address (192.168.1.72) they don't work.

[image]

Side-by-side

[image]

I can ping the 192.168.1.72 address just fine.

[image]

Why can't I access via ip, and how would I do so?

Comment: The site bindings simply accept localhost requests only, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html If you want to access via IP, you need to modify the bindings.

Comment: And how/where would I modify

Comment: Either manually or via a tool like Jexus Manager, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#background

Comment: I installed Jexus Manager and got my project on there. But its not clear at all how I can run a debug from inside VS2017, and then have Jexus give me an ip address.

Comment: First, add a binding that accepts access via IP. Then test and make sure that Jexus Manager can start the site and the browser works. And lastly you go back to VS and sync the settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`IIS Express` does not allow remote connections by default.

Here are two options for you:

1. Configure to use `UseKestrel` like

   ```
   public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000;https://0.0.0.0:5001")
           .UseKestrel()
           .UseStartup<Startup>();
   ```

   Then, run project with `ProjectName` from VS, you will be able to access by `http//ip:5000`
2. Try to create IIS Debug profile

   Run VS 2017 as administrator-> Right Click project-> Properties->Debug->NEW->Enter `IIS`->Launch choose IIS-> Launch IIS Profile-> Access with ip address

Update:

If you insist on `IIS Express`, try the VS Extension [Conveyor by Keyoti](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti)

Comment: it worked, the port `5000` needs to be the same as in `launchSettings.json` for `http` profile,

Answer (score 4):

There is a little open-source github repository to make this work. it is a small portable executable (.exe) app that makes your API (port actually) accessible via local network.

[image: sharp proxy]

repo link: https://github.com/jocull/SharpProxy

Comment: This is the best tool EVER!

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler solution if you have admin access to your pc, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11535395/167304

Given web app running on `localhost:1234` with ip `10.10.10.10`:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=1234 listenaddress=10.10.10.10 connectport=1234 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

When no longer needed, delete the record

```
netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=1234 listenaddress=10.10.10.10
```

For more detail see [netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy#add-v4tov4)