# How to deploy dotnet core application on Ubuntu server with Nginx server?

Tags: linux, nginx, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04, amazon-lightsail

I have a dotnet core application built on dotnet core 3.1 and when I tried to deploy the same in ubuntu 18.04 server by following the steps given in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but not able to access the app on port 80 (accessing through public IP)

Here is the Nginx updated  configuration

[image]

and dotnet application is running with port 5000 and 5001 (for now I didn't configure service to the same)

[image]

Getting the following error when accessing through the browsers ( public IP)

[image]

I'm missing any configurations?

Comment: Please show the config as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was IISexpress port access issue.

By default, the IISexpress does not allow the external network to access the port and this access needs an explicit configuration.

If you are facing the same problem, you can find the code snippet and other details here.

[Accessing IISExpress for an asp.net core API via IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54500310/accessing-iisexpress-for-an-asp-net-core-api-via-ip)