# How to access ASP.NET Core web server from another device

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created a project using C# and ASP.NET Core empty and it worked on `localhost` - how can I access it from another device using the IP of the computer running the project?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Execute the `ipconfig` in command prompt of your system to know the IP address, and then use it on another system's browser as http:// 16x.n.n.n:5000 , if it is in same network it should work. If there is any firewall on your system that prevents inbound on non standard ports, you need to add a rule to allow port 5000 inbound traffic.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I got the IPv4 address from `ipconfig` but when I access `http://my_ip:5000` I can't access it

Comment: As suspected :-).  See if you can reach to that ip from your device, using ping, and telnet kind of tools. Is it resolving and giving HTTP error code, or is it not resolving the IP addr itself?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran On the device running the project if I run `http://my_ip` I can access xampp website and I access `http://my_ip:5000` I can't access it, for external devices whether I access `http:my_ip` or `http://my_ip:5000` is not working

Comment: You need to configure your xampp webserver as shown in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to/48990347#48990347)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing IISExpress for an asp.net core API via IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54500310/accessing-iisexpress-for-an-asp-net-core-api-via-ip)

Comment: nothing answers the question, is not that simple. Please if you know give us some clue. Django works with same address, same port, why .NET cannot?

Comment: you need a binding to ip address in your application , so web server (depends which one you using) kestrel, iis... will know how to redirect requests.

Answer (score 20):

You need to configure kestrel to bind requests from 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost to accept requests from everywhere.

You can achieve this with different methods.

1- Run application with `urls` argument

`dotnet app.dll --urls "http://0.0.0.0:5000;https://0.0.0.0:5001"`

2- Add kestrel config to appsettings.json (Or any other way that you can inject value to IConfiguration)

```
{
 ...
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://0.0.0.0:5001"
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

3- Hard-code your binding in the program.cs file.

and the result should look like this

[image]

For complete details, please visit
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints

Comment: not working for me on .NET 6 , windows 10

Comment: Worked for me on Asp .Net Core 6 , MacOS.

Comment: I receive the below error on iPhone when changing from https://localhost:7139 to https://0.0.0.0:7139. It worked on my laptop (where LiveServer was running) 

`Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “192.168.0.10”, which could put your confidential information at risk.`

Comment: @Ollie use http instead on https. Your certificate is only valid on localhost.

Comment: it worked for me. Thank you very much. I've been looking for an answer for hours.
ASP NET CORE 3.1

Answer (score 2):

For .Net 6.0 API, in `launchsettings.json`, I changed all the `localhost` values to `0.0.0.0`.[image: shot of launchsettings showing 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative and easier option for access from other devices, you can use Ngrok. It will make your localhost accessible and public from the outside and for other devices. Setting up and installing everything you need will take about 5 minutes. If you suddenly don’t figure out how to set up Ngrok, I attach a video tutorial [step by step](https://youtu.be/KcbUaZ2a4hc)